# Take count of unique values within distinct codes after search value with different node (XSLT 1)

Tags: count, sum, xslt-1.0, distinct-values

I want to get grouping of node using `/continuitydays/ES_CONTINUITYDAY/txevents/ES_BMTXEVENT/txortxeventproduct/ES_PRODUCT/@p_episode_seriestitle` node then after i want to count of how many episode are belong .but here episode are repeated multiple time so i want to make unique using `/continuitydays/ES_CONTINUITYDAY/txevents/ES_BMTXEVENT/transmission/ES_TRANSMISSION/@tx_external_reference`  this xpath .using this XPATH only one records will be pick and consider only that raw in count and sum function.

Episode Count using below XPATH:

```
count(/continuitydays/ES_CONTINUITYDAY/txevents/ES_BMTXEVENT[txortxeventproduct/ES_PRODUCT/@p_episode_seriestitle='101 Dalmatian Street S1'])
```

Duration using below XPATH:

```
SUM(/continuitydays/ES_CONTINUITYDAY/txevents/ES_BMTXEVENT[txortxeventproduct/ES_PRODUCT/@p_episode_seriestitle='101 Dalmatian Street S1']/startTimePointInUtc/ESP_TIMEINSTANT/@duration)       


count(/continuitydays/ES_CONTINUITYDAY/txevents/ES_BMTXEVENT[txortxeventproduct/ES_PRODUCT/@p_episode_seriestitle='101 Dalmatian Street S1']/transmission/ES_TRANSMISSION/@tx_external_reference)
```

It gives me 6 count for episode ,but actual count is only 3.
Logic for sub grouping(3 count)
First grouping of p_episode_seriestitle then count of all episode with distinct value of /continuitydays/ES_CONTINUITYDAY/txevents/ES_BMTXEVENT/txortxeventproduct/ES_PRODUCT/@p_product_title and 
/continuitydays/ES_CONTINUITYDAY/txevents/ES_BMTXEVENT/transmission/ES_TRANSMISSION/@tx_external_reference

My source code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" version="1.0"/>
    <xsl:template match="continuitydays">
        <xsl:for-each select="ES_CONTINUITYDAY/txevents/ES_BMTXEVENT">
            <!--check duplicate season title-->
            <xsl:variable name="lvSeriesTitle" select="txortxeventproduct/ES_PRODUCT/@p_episode_seriestitle"/>
            <xsl:variable name="lvRepeatable">
                <xsl:call-template name="repeatableEpisode">
                    <xsl:with-param name="index" select="position()"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="repeatableName" select="$lvSeriesTitle"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="filterPath" select="//continuitydays/ES_CONTINUITYDAY/txevents/ES_BMTXEVENT"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <!-- skipping if episode is more than one in season -->
            <xsl:if test="string-length($lvRepeatable) = 0">
                <xsl:variable name="lvEpisodeTitleTypePath" select="/continuitydays/ES_CONTINUITYDAY/txevents/ES_BMTXEVENT[txortxeventproduct/ES_PRODUCT/p_episode_series/ES_PRODUCT/@p_product_title = $lvSeriesTitle]"/>
                <!--         Episode Count using below XPATH:
    count(/continuitydays/ES_CONTINUITYDAY/txevents/ES_BMTXEVENT[txortxeventproduct/ES_PRODUCT/@p_episode_seriestitle='101 Dalmatian Street S1'])

    Duration using below XPATH:
    SUM(/continuitydays/ES_CONTINUITYDAY/txevents/ES_BMTXEVENT[txortxeventproduct/ES_PRODUCT/@p_episode_seriestitle='101 Dalmatian Street S1']/startTimePointInUtc/ESP_TIMEINSTANT/@duration)   -->
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="repeatableEpisode">
        <xsl:param name="index"/>
        <xsl:param name="repeatableName"/>
        <xsl:param name="filterPath"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$filterPath">
            <xsl:if test="position() &lt; $index">
                <xsl:if test="$repeatableName = txortxeventproduct/ES_PRODUCT/@p_episode_seriestitle">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Source:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <continuitydays>
        <ES_CONTINUITYDAY>
            <channel>
                <ESP_CHANNEL name="Disney Channel France" usercode="DCFR">
                    <popupLookups/>
                    <pressTarget>
                        <ESP_PRESSTARGET name="French" lot_external_reference="French">
                            <popupLookups/>
                        </ESP_PRESSTARGET>
                    </pressTarget>
                    <children/>
                </ESP_CHANNEL>
            </channel>
            <txdate>
                <ESP_DATE date="2022-03-26" year="2022" month="3" day="26" dayname="Saturday" weekdaynumber="6" weeknumber="13" monthname="March" dateindays="44279"/>
            </txdate>
            <txevents>
                <ES_BMTXEVENT>
                    <transmission>
                        <ES_TRANSMISSION tx_title="101 Dalmatian Street S1 Ep 1" tx_external_reference="30793929812"/>
                    </transmission>
                    <txortxeventproduct>
                        <ES_PRODUCT p_product_type="Episode" p_product_title="101 Dalmatian Street S1 Ep 1" p_episode_seriestitle="101 Dalmatian Street S1"/>
                    </txortxeventproduct>
                    <startTimePointInUtc>
                        <ESP_TIMEINSTANT hours="5" minutes="0" seconds="0" duration="300:00.000" time="05:00:00.000"/>
                    </startTimePointInUtc>
                </ES_BMTXEVENT>
                <ES_BMTXEVENT>
                    <transmission>
                        <ES_TRANSMISSION tx_title="101 Dalmatian Street S1 Ep 1" tx_external_reference="30793929812"/>
                    </transmission>
                    <txortxeventproduct>
                        <ES_PRODUCT p_product_type="Episode" p_product_title="101 Dalmatian Street S1 Ep 1" p_episode_seriestitle="101 Dalmatian Street S1"/>
                    </txortxeventproduct>
                    <startTimePointInUtc>
                        <ESP_TIMEINSTANT hours="5" minutes="0" seconds="0" duration="300:00.000" time="05:00:00.000"/>
                    </startTimePointInUtc>
                </ES_BMTXEVENT>
                <ES_BMTXEVENT>
                    <transmission>
                        <ES_TRANSMISSION tx_title="101 Dalmatian Street S1 Ep 1" tx_external_reference="30793929813"/>
                    </transmission>
                    <txortxeventproduct>
                        <ES_PRODUCT p_product_type="Episode" p_product_title="101 Dalmatian Street S1 Ep 1" p_episode_seriestitle="101 Dalmatian Street S1"/>
                    </txortxeventproduct>
                    <startTimePointInUtc>
                        <ESP_TIMEINSTANT hours="5" minutes="0" seconds="0" duration="300:00.000" time="05:00:00.000"/>
                    </startTimePointInUtc>
                </ES_BMTXEVENT>
                <ES_BMTXEVENT>
                    <transmission>
                        <ES_TRANSMISSION tx_title="101 Dalmatian Street S1 Ep 1" tx_external_reference="30793929813"/>
                    </transmission>
                    <txortxeventproduct>
                        <ES_PRODUCT p_product_type="Episode" p_product_title="101 Dalmatian Street S1 Ep 1" p_episode_seriestitle="101 Dalmatian Street S1"/>
                    </txortxeventproduct>
                    <startTimePointInUtc>
                        <ESP_TIMEINSTANT hours="5" minutes="0" seconds="0" duration="300:00.000" time="05:00:00.000"/>
                    </startTimePointInUtc>
                </ES_BMTXEVENT>
                <ES_BMTXEVENT>
                    <transmission>
                        <ES_TRANSMISSION tx_title="101 Dalmatian Street S1 Ep 2" tx_external_reference="30803303812"/>
                    </transmission>
                    <txortxeventproduct>
                        <ES_PRODUCT p_product_type="Episode" p_product_title="101 Dalmatian Street S1 Ep 2" p_episode_seriestitle="101 Dalmatian Street S1"/>
                    </txortxeventproduct>
                    <startTimePointInUtc>
                        <ESP_TIMEINSTANT hours="10" minutes="12" seconds="40" duration="612:40.000" time="10:12:40.000"/>
                    </startTimePointInUtc>
                </ES_BMTXEVENT>
                <ES_BMTXEVENT>
                    <transmission>
                        <ES_TRANSMISSION tx_title="101 Dalmatian Street S1 Ep 2" tx_external_reference="30803303812"/>
                    </transmission>
                    <txortxeventproduct>
                        <ES_PRODUCT p_product_type="Episode" p_product_title="101 Dalmatian Street S1 Ep 2" p_episode_seriestitle="101 Dalmatian Street S1"/>
                    </txortxeventproduct>
                    <startTimePointInUtc>
                        <ESP_TIMEINSTANT hours="10" minutes="12" seconds="40" duration="612:40.000" time="10:12:40.000"/>
                    </startTimePointInUtc>
                </ES_BMTXEVENT>
            </txevents>
        </ES_CONTINUITYDAY>
    </continuitydays>
```

Wrong Output as below :

```
    Title                      Episode Count    Duration
    101 Dalmatian Street S1    6                    2424.8
```

I want Output as below :

```
    Title                      Episode Count    Duration
    101 Dalmatian Street S1    3                    1212.4
```

Comment: I see 6 events and 2 distinct titles. By what logic do you count 3?

Comment: P.S. In general, grouping in XSLT 1.0 is done using the Muenchian method - see: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: I dont want that unique title based count.
First grouping based on below XPATH  :/continuitydays/ES_CONTINUITYDAY/txevents/ES_BMTXEVENT/txortxeventproduct/ES_PRODUCT/@p_episode_seriestitle                   ,Then i want count all episodes and duartion

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Using MUENCHIAN METHOD i didn't calculating count with distinct value and sum with distinct values

Comment: Using Muenchian grouping by title would produce: `"101 Dalmatian Street S1 Ep 1" =>  3 x 300:00.000; "101 Dalmatian Street S1 Ep 2" => 2 x 612:40.000`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k  First, grouping of episode series title =>101 Dalmatian Street S1 =>then get distinct raw  of  tx_external_reference => it gives me total 3 count and 1212.4 sum of duration

Comment: @tim-c    Can you please look into my problem ?